# Unable to create a Thing in AWS IoT using AWS sdk for Android

Tags: android, aws-iot

How to create a Thing in AWS IoT using AWS sdk for android? Every time I try to execute my code it fails with a Network exception error. My target is to create a Thing with a Thing Name which will be visible in the AWS IoT dashboard. Below is what I tried.

```
CreateThingRequest thingRequest = new CreateThingRequest();
thingRequest.withThingName("NewTestThing");
CreateThingResult thingResult = mIoTAndroidClient.createThing(thingRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing android logs will be helpful. Also, do check that you are not running the snippet of code in the main thread.